# System rules returns different line separator

Tags: java, spring, junit, system-rules

I have a spring test class from `Spring in Action 4th` which tests simple class that prints something to standard output. It uses `System-Rules` library incorporated into junit.

When I run the test it throwed `ComparisionException` - the only difference was line separator. Eventually I managed to bypass it by fetching line separator from `System.properties`.

Is it somehow possible to configure System-Rules to make it automatically ?
I'm using windows 7 professional.

**Test**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.StandardOutputStreamLog;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:META-INF/spring/soundsystem.xml")
public class CDPlayerXMLConfigTest {

    private String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");//This will retrieve line separator dependent on OS.

    @Rule
    public final StandardOutputStreamLog log = new StandardOutputStreamLog();

    @Autowired
    private MediaPlayer player;

    @Autowired
    private CompactDisc cd;

    @Test
    public void cdShouldNotBeNull() {
        assertNotNull(cd);
    }

    @Test // Won't pass
    public void play() {
        player.play();
        assertEquals("Playing Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band by The Beatles\n", log.getLog());
    }

    @Test //Will pass
    public void play2() {
        player.play();
        assertEquals("Playing Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band by The Beatles" + newLine, log.getLog());
    }
}
```

**Tested class**

```
@Component
public class SgtPeppers implements CompactDisc {

    private String title = "Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band";
    private String artist = "The Beatles";

    public void play() {
        System.out.println("Playing " + title + " by " + artist);
    }

}
```

Comment: `Is it somehow possible to configure System-Rules to make it automatically?` ... to make *what* automatically? Your test `play()` won't pass on a Windows system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System Rules just returns what has been written to `System.out`. I added a new method `log.getLogWithNormalizedLineSeparator()` to [System Rules 1.12.0](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/releases.html) that solves your problem. (You have to use the new rule `SystemOutRule` instead of `StandardOutputStreamLog`.)

Answer (score 0):

This is test from that book:

```
package com.springbook.stereo;

import com.springbook.CDPlayerConfig;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.SystemOutRule;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= CDPlayerConfig.class)
public class CDPlayerTest {

    @Rule
    public final SystemOutRule log =
            new SystemOutRule().enableLog();

    @Autowired
    private MediaPlayer player;

    @Autowired
    private CompactDisc cd;

    @Test
    public void cdShouldNotBeNull() {
        assertNotNull(cd);
    }
    @Test
    public void play(){
        player.play();
        Assert.assertEquals("Playing Sgt. Papper's Lonely Hearts Club Band, band The Beatles\n", log.getLogWithNormalizedLineSeparator());
    }
}
```